# Is there a good tool to aggregate django error messages for a site?

Tags: python, django, error-handling

We've used Arecibo, but the configuration of it and dealing with AppEngine were painful. Does anyone have other or better tools for this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sentry/raven. https://www.getsentry.com/welcome/ and https://github.com/dcramer/sentry/

It's open source and you can run your own server and there's very good Django integration. If you just want to quickly test it you can use their commercial service's trial (no special need, but to save you setting up the server).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - Sentry is awesome!